# Assign alert tone for UILocalNotification from available sounds in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, alert, uilocalnotification

I am working on an app that used UILocalNotification. I wanted to select sound from default sounds that came with iPhone. How can i list down sounds for assign as the alert tone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one standard sound for notification from system (`UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`). You can play any custom sound shorter than 30 seconds. So, if you can download any native sound from ios from anywhere, you will be able to use it as custom sound. [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName)